# Math with my keyframe multiple animation not working using CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, keyframe

I've spent the past little while reading up on @keyframes and animation CSS (because honestly my coding skills were stuck mid naughties!) and while I understand how it works in theory my maths isn't working.

What I want is three items to fade in and out over 15 seconds so on an infinite loop.

Item 1 - opacity: 0 at 0% and opacity 1 at 33% then back to opacity 0 for the next 10 seconds (66% and 100%)
Item 2 - opacity: 0 at 0% and 33% before fading in to opacity 1 by 66% and then back out
Item 3 - opacity 0 for the first ten seconds and then fade in to opacity 1 by 99%/100%

The CSS that I have at the moment is

```css
.testimonial-slider {
   display: block;
   width: 50%;
   height: auto;
   margin-top: 100px;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider {
   display: block;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider li {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.testimonial-slider ul.slider li:nth-child(1) {
   
    -webkit-animation: fade-animation-1 15s infinite;
            animation: fade-animation-1 15s infinite;
}
.testimonial-slider ul.slider li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: fade-animation-2 15s infinite;
            animation: fade-animation-2 15s infinite;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider li:nth-child(3) {

    -webkit-animation: fade-animation-3 15s infinite;
            animation: fade-animation-3 15s infinite;

.testimonial-slider q {
   display: inline-block;
   font: normal 30px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
   letter-spacing: .5pt;
   text-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
   }

.testimonial-slider .source {
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font: italic 20px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* KEYFRAME DECLARATIONS */

@keyframes fade-animation 1 {

0% {opacity:0;}
33% {opacity:1;}
65% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes fade-animation 2 {

0% {opacity:0}
33% {opacity:0}
66% {opacity:1}
100% {opacity:0}

@keyframes fade-animation 3 {

0% {opacity:0}
33% {opacity:0}
66% {opacity:0}
99% {opacity:1}
100% {opacity:0}


@-webkit-keyframes fade-animation-1 {
0% {opacity:0;}
33% {opacity:1;}
65% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-animation-2 {
0% {opacity:0}
33% {opacity:0}
66% {opacity:1}
100% {opacity:0}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-animation 3 {

0% {opacity:0}
33% {opacity:0}
66% {opacity:0}
99% {opacity:1}
100% {opacity:0}
```

and the corresponding HTML

```html
   <div class="testimonial-slider" style="padding:5px;">
        <ul class="slider">
          <li>
            <div class="testimonial-slider-content"> <q>Such a great testimonial goes here!!! Yay!!!.</q>
              <p class="source">- Chair</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="testimonial-slider-content"> <q>Testimonial 2 content oh yay great testimonial</q>
              <p class="source">- Head of Investor Relations</p>
            </div>
          </li>
           <li>
            <div class="testimonial-slider-content"> <q>Testimonial content here 
</q>
              <p class="source">- CEO/Founder</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your code is working fine. The only problem is that you don't have some curly brackets closed.

```css
.testimonial-slider {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider li:nth-child(1){
  -webkit-animation: fade-animation-1 15s infinite;
  animation: fade-animation-1 15s infinite;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: fade-animation-2 15s infinite;
  animation: fade-animation-2 15s infinite;
}

.testimonial-slider ul.slider li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: fade-animation-3 15s infinite;
  animation: fade-animation-3 15s infinite;
}

.testimonial-slider q {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal 30px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .5pt;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.testimonial-slider .source {
  margin-top: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font: italic 20px Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* KEYFRAME DECLARATIONS */

@keyframes fade-animation-1 {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  33% {opacity:1;}
  65% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@keyframes fade-animation-2 {
  0% {opacity:0}
  33% {opacity:0}
  66% {opacity:1}
  100% {opacity:0}
}

@keyframes fade-animation-3 {
  0% {opacity:0}
  33% {opacity:0}
  66% {opacity:0}
  99% {opacity:1}
  100% {opacity:0}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-animation-1 {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  33% {opacity:1;}
  65% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-animation-2 {
  0% {opacity:0}
  33% {opacity:0}
  66% {opacity:1}
  100% {opacity:0}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-animation-3 {
  0% {opacity:0}
  33% {opacity:0}
  66% {opacity:0}
  99% {opacity:1}
  100% {opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-slider" style="padding:5px;">
        <ul class="slider">
          <li>
            <div class="testimonial-slider-content"> <q>Such a great testimonial goes here!!! Yay!!!.</q>
              <p class="source">- Chair</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="testimonial-slider-content"> <q>Testimonial 2 content oh yay great testimonial</q>
              <p class="source">- Head of Investor Relations</p>
            </div>
          </li>
           <li>
            <div class="testimonial-slider-content"> <q>Testimonial content here 
</q>
              <p class="source">- CEO/Founder</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Regards

Comment: Well that's awkward. I guess I'd been staring at the code for too long. 

Except it's not working 100% the third testimonial isn't actually appearing

Comment: Hello again mate. You were right. I edited the code and it's working now. I forgot the dash in fade-animation-3.

Comment: Amazing!!! But don't worry I didn't even notice that was missing lol

Comment: Hi @Ricardo Silva or anyone else. Coming back to the code above I've now had to add a fourth testimonial and in changing the maths I've seem to have stuffed up the code again ugh

https://codepen.io/autisticenbynerd/pen/VwXWwzG is the new code
https://codepen.io/autisticenbynerd/pen/vYRZYeQ is the original code that worked fine
https://songsofstardust.com/resolve/testimonials.html is the live test version of the code that I'm editing